# Stored procedure SQL optimization

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Im running a query and its taking a long time. Here is my sample code:

```
SELECT @AppleCount=COUNT(*) 
FROM (
 SELECT * FROM @iDToStoreMapping  sm 
 WHERE StoreFront=73 
 AND sm.CategoryCountryCategoryTYpeMappingID NOT IN 
 (SELECT * FROM @FinishedDls)
) rows
```

@AppleCount is supposed to be all the categoryCountryCategoryTypeMappingId's in existence and @FinishedDls has that id if an application finished its download and wrote that id in there, so this query is supposed to get the count of those ids which haven't downloaded yet. There's about 50k ids. and i have to run this query 3 times, but each one takes a couple mins. Is there anything im doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes using an explicit `join` instead of `not in` results in better performance:

```
SELECT @AppleCount = COUNT(*) 
FROM @iDToStoreMapping  sm left outer join
     @FinishedDls fd
     on sm.CategoryCountryCategoryTYpeMappingID = fd.id
WHERE StoreFront = 73 and
      fd.id is null;
```

Comment: answered my self +1 for effort and useful information

Answer (score 0):

I didnt use a primary key on my table variables and that is what caused the terrible performance. Sorry everyone.